# Independence and expectational independece?

Tags: random-variables

Let X and Y be two random variables and

$E[f_1(X), f_2(Y)] = E[f_1(X)] *E[f_2(Y)]$

then can I conclude that $f_1(X)$ and $f_2(Y)$ are independent?

Comment: $f_1(X)$ and $f_2(Y)$ are always independent given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @d.k.o. edited, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Take $X=Z$ and $Y=Z^2$, where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Then $\mathsf{E}XY=\mathsf{E}Z^3=0=\mathsf{E}X\mathsf{E}Y$. In your case $f_1(X)$ and $f_2(Y)$ are just uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

If your equation $E[f(X)g(Y)]=(E[f(X)])(E[g(Y)])$ holds for enough different functions the answer becomes *yes*.  Such as, the set of all $f,g$ of form $x\mapsto\mathbb 1_{[a,b]}(x)$, or the set of all continuous bounded $f,g$, or the set of all functions of form $u\mapsto\exp(au)$, etc.